# Set font size of values numbers on the axis

Tags: gnuplot, gnu

How do I set the font size for the values on both the x and y-axis?

I've looked around and I've only found ways to change the `xlabel`'s size and `ylabel`'s size, but I want the actual numbers below the axis to be bigger.

Comment: Similar challenge has been in Matlab where I have found the PaperSize option the best way to get consistent fonts. Similar procedure can also work in Gnuplot so I opened a new thread about it here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29727851/54964

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Small elaboration on bb2's answer, if you do not want to change the font face:

```
set xtics font ", 30"
```

And for tics on the yaxis:

```
set ytics font ", 30"
```

For both axis at the same time:

```
set tics font ", 30"
```

Comment: This is what bothered me for ages, how to set font size without knowing the current font. Thank you.

Comment: Does not work for me with epslatex output terminal driver

Answer (score 29):

It was with:

```
set xtics font "Times-Roman, 30"
```