# PaperSize option for Gnuplot in fitting fonts?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, gnu

I used to set `PaperSize` in Matlab to control the font size in different axis. 
This is better than directly changing the fontsize. 
I think this kind of procedure can be working for gnuplot too.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7576598/54964) some overview of papersize in Matlab. 
An unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15732856/54964) in SO about setting fontsize with partisan view how to do it.

So Matlab's command

```
set(hFig, 'PaperSize',[X Y])
```

**Is there any similar way to control the papersize in Gnuplot as Matlab?** 
I want to get consistent font sizes in my plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the overall image size with the terminals `size` option like

```
set terminal pdfcairo size 21cm,29.7cm
```

Comment: My terminal is qt. I cannot find any size which match good size of the screen (Macbook air); cm is not allowed, only pixels. Etc `set terminal qt size 1280,720` working bad. I would like to get the output to Qt first without creation of the file.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question: what's your final output? Screen, PNG (or similar, pixel-based), or vector format? And yes, a screen is pixel-based, and giving units like centimetres wouldn't make sense. So, what is bad with `set terminal qt size 1280,720`?

Comment: Actually, nothing anymore. There was some conflict in my terminal which caused the window to be in strange configuration. I logged off and now the  image is as it should be.